# How to get a button to click in the parent from a child

Tags: angular

I have the code as below.  I am trying to figure out how to get the parent to react to the click of the "edit" button in the parent html.  Can someone tell me what I am missing?  Basically the parent has the router-outlet where the child is displayed, and the edit button is part of the parent html.  The code is not reacting to the click on the edit button.

My desire is to have the router-outlet display a form as a different child in the 'display' area of the page when the user clicks the 'edit' button.  In other words, I only want the page to change where the router-outlet is stipulated in the html of the parent.[image]

Parent:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';
// import { Menu } from 'primeng/menu';
// import { style } from '@angular/animations';
import { AppMenuService } from '../services/app-menu.service';
import { AppMenu } from '../models/app-menu.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homescreen',
  templateUrl: './homescreen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homescreen.component.css'],
  providers: [AppMenuService]
})
export class HomescreenComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'niche-app Home';
  appMenu: AppMenu;

  constructor(private appMenuService: AppMenuService) { }

  items: MenuItem[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appMenu = this.appMenuService.getAppMenu();
    this.items = [{
      label: 'Menu', style: "background-color: red",
      items: [
        { label: 'Home', routerLink: "/home", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        { label: 'Our Company', routerLink: "/ourcompany.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        **{ label: 'Products', routerLink: "/product.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },**
        { label: 'Company', routerLink: "/company.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        { label: 'Contact Information', routerLink: "/contact.info.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        { label: 'Shipment Information', routerLink: "/shipment.info.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        { label: 'Parent ASINs', routerLink: "/parent.asin.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        { label: 'Competitors To Target', routerLink: "/competitors.to.target.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        { label: 'Checkpoint Criteria', routerLink: "/checkpoint.criteria.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        { label: 'Criteria Yes Nos', routerLink: "/criteria.yes.no.component", routerLinkActiveOptions: "active" },
        { label: 'Download', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-download' }
      ]
    }];
  }

  handleEdit() {
    console.log("handleEdit(): Called...");
  }

}
    <div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">
        <p-menu class="left-menu" [model]="items" id="itemsId"></p-menu>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-10 ui-g-nopad">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <p-toolbar id="toolbarId">
                <div class="ui-toolbar-group-left">
                    <button pButton type="button" label="New" icon="pi pi-plus" id="newBtn"></button>
                    **<button pButton type="button" label="Edit" icon="pi pi-search" id="editBtn" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="handleEdit($event)"></button>**
                    <button pButton type="button" label="Upload" icon="pi pi-upload" class="ui-button-success"
                        id="uploadBtn"></button>

                    <i class="pi pi-bars"></i>

                    <p-splitButton label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" [model]="items" styleClass="ui-button-warning"
                        id="saveBtn"></p-splitButton>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-toolbar-group-right">
                    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" id="searchId"></button>
                    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-calendar" class="ui-button-success"
                        id="calendarBtn"></button>
                    <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger" id="exitBtn"></button>
                </div>
            </p-toolbar>
        </div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
        <!-- <p-panel header="Footer" [showHeader]=false style="border-top-style:solid; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-color: rgb(200,200,200)"> -->
        <p-panel header="Footer" [showHeader]=false id="footerId">
            Some text
        </p-panel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';
import { ProductStore } from 'src/app/stores/product-store';
import { Company } from 'src/app/models/company.model';
import { AppMenu } from 'src/app/models/app-menu.model';
import { AppMenuService } from 'src/app/services/app-menu.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  appMenu: AppMenu;

  products: Product[];

  originalId: number;
  selectedProduct: Product = {
    id: null,
    asin: '',
    productPageLink: '',
    twentyOnePointScore: null,
    primeLowPrice: null,
    totalUnitsSoldPerMonth: null,
    totalRevenuePerMonth: null,
    numberOfCompetitiveSellers: null,
    unitsPerMonth: null,
    revenuePerMonth: null,
    estimatedProductCost: null,
    actualProductCost: null,
    estimatedAmazonFees: null,
    actualAmazonFees: null,
    estimatedShippingCost: null,
    actualShippingCost: null,
    estimatedProcessingCost: null,
    actualProcessingCost: null,
    estimatedProfitMargin: null,
    actualProfitMargin: null,
    estimatedROI: null,
    actualROI: null,
    companys: null,
    contactInfos: null,
    criteriaYesNos: null,
    competitorsToTarget: null,
    shipmentInfo: null,
    parentAsin: null,
    notes: '',
    createdBy: '',
    createdDate: null,
    updatedBy: '',
    updatedDate: null
  };

  @Input() set product(value: Product) {
    if (value) {
      this.originalId = value.id;
    }
    this.selectedProduct = Object.assign({}, value);
  }

  constructor(private productStore: ProductStore, private appMenuService: AppMenuService) {
    this.productStore.init();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appMenu = this.appMenuService.getAppMenu();
    console.log("id=" + this.appMenu.id);
    console.log("screenName=" + this.appMenu.screenName);
    console.log("url" + this.appMenu.url);
    this.appMenu.id = 3;
    this.appMenu.screenName = "productScreen";
    this.appMenu.url = "/product.component";
    this.appMenuService.setAppMenu(this.appMenu);
   this.productStore.getAll$().subscribe(products => { this.products = products; })
  }

  routeToCompanies(product: Product): void {
    // TODO need to query for companies associted with the product.  This means the controller on the backend needs a method for this.
    this.selectedProduct = product;
    console.log('routeToCompanies(): called...');
    var companies: Company[] = product.companys;
    for (var i in companies) {
      console.log("ID=" + companies[i].id)
      console.log("Company Name=" + companies[i].companyName)
    }
    console.log("id=" + this.appMenu.id);
    console.log("screenName=" + this.appMenu.screenName);
    console.log("url=" + this.appMenu.url);
    // this.store.dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_AUTHOR', payload: this.selectedAuthor });
    // this.router.navigate(['/home/authors/detail']);
  }
}

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <p-dataTable [value]="products" [rows]="10" expandableRows="true" [paginator]="true" [responsive]="true"
      selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedProduct">
      <p-header>
        <b>Products</b>
      </p-header>
      <p-column expander="true" styleClass="col-icon" [style]="{'width': '30px'}"></p-column>
      <!-- <p-column field="id" header="ID" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '3%'}"></p-column> -->
      <p-column field="id" header="ID" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width': '3%'}"></p-column>
      <p-column field="asin" header="ASIN" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
      <p-column field="totalRevenuePerMonth" header="Total/Month" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
      <p-column field="primeLowPrice" header="Prime Low Price" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
      <p-column field="totalUnitsSoldPerMonth" header="Monthly Units Sold" [sortable]="true"></p-column>

      <ng-template let-product pTemplate="rowexpansion">
          <div class="p-grid p-dir-col">
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Page Link: </b>{{ product.productPageLink }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Number Of Competitive Sellers: </b>{{ product.numberOfCompetitiveSellers }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Units Per Month: </b>{{ product.unitsPerMonth }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Estimated Product Cost: </b>{{ product.estimatedProductCost }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Actual Product Cost: </b>{{ product.actualProductCost }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Estimated Amazon Fees: </b>{{ product.estimatedAmazonFees }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Actual Amazon Fees: </b>{{ product.actualAmazonFees }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product EstimatedShippCost: </b>{{ product.estimatedShippingCost }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Actual Shipping Cost: </b>{{ product.actualShippingCost }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Actual Processing Cost: </b>{{ product.actualProcessingCost }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Estimated Processing Cost: </b>{{ product.estimatedProcessingCost }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Estimated Profit Margin: </b>{{ product.estimatedProfitMargin }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Estimated ROI: </b>{{ product.estimatedROI }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Actual ROI: </b>{{ product.actualROI }}</div>

              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Record created date: </b>{{ product.createdDate | date }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Record created by: </b>{{ product.createdBy }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Record last updated: </b>{{ product.updatedDate | date }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Record last updated by: </b>{{ product.updatedBy }}</div>
              <div class="p-col p-col-align-start"><b>Product Notes: </b>{{ product.notes }}</div>             
          </div>
          <div>
              <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" label="Contact Info" class="ui-button-raised ui-button-info" style="margin-right: .25em"></button>
              <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" label="Checkpoint Criteria" class="ui-button-raised ui-button-info" style="margin-right: .25em"></button>
              <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" label="Competitors To Target" class="ui-button-raised ui-button-info" style="margin-right: .25em"></button>
              <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" label="Shipment Info" class="ui-button-raised ui-button-info" style="margin-right: .25em"></button>
              <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-search" label="Parent Asin" class="ui-button-raised ui-button-info"></button>
          </div>
      </ng-template>
      <p-column field="companys" header="Companies" [sortable]="false" [filter]="false" [style]="{'width': '100px'}">
        <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
          <span class="fa fa-search fa-15" (click)="routeToCompanies(row)">
            <span class="sr-only">View Company</span>
          </span>
        </ng-template>
      </p-column>

    </p-dataTable>
    <!-- <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-right:0px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px"
                (click)="addAuthor()">Add Author</button>
        </div> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a service to communicate between components

Comment: check this https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: you can not make using routing and navigation?

Comment: As indicated below in my question to Prasanth, why isn't the (click)="handleEdit($event)" not responding to the click in the parent page?  I already have a service for the menu.  I want the handleEdit to read the observable for the screen name and then route to a new child component, but the (click) doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service like below

```
    @Injectable()
export class Service {
    constructor() { }

    private emitChangeSource = new Subject<any>();

    changeEmitted$ = this.emitChangeSource.asObservable();

    emitChange() {
        this.emitChangeSource.next();
    }
}
```

Your parent component

```
constructor(
    private service: Service
    ) {
   }

   login(){
    this.service.emitChange()
   }
```

Your child component:

```
constructor(
    private service: Service,
    ) { 
    service.changeEmitted$.subscribe(data => {
      // here fetch data from the session storage 
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Prasanth.  I will attempt this either tonight or tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: In looking at this a little more, why isn't the click in the parent being detected?  The handleEvent in                   <button pButton type="button" label="Edit" icon="pi pi-search" id="editBtn" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="handleEdit($event)"></button>
 should do the trick.

Comment: After doing some more trial and error, I found that the click does work if you are on the homescreen, which is the parent to all the other screens, but once the app routes to one of the other child components, the parent homescreen does not react to the click event.  Does anyone have any clues as to why that is?

Answer (score 0):

I marked Prasanth answer as the correct one because it is the best answer.  There are other ways to do component interaction, but the one he offered does work.  Anil's link above is a good reference and worth the read.

That said, I already do have a service.  The issue is that this question really had nothing to do with the problem in that it was too general.  Of course, this is my fault.

The issue was that the parent was not responding to the (click) from the child because I had the router-outlet placed incorrectly in the parent HTML page.  Once, I made the correction, the (click) started to work.

Thank all you who responded.